# Changing icon after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm currently trying to setup so after I click on an icon the the icon should change. I can get everything else to work exept the icon change. I think its because i don't have the condition right. 
Maybe im doing it wrong but i don't know. Please tell me if so.

Basically I have two icons, one that opens the datetimepicker modal and after the notification has been 
set the icon should change to cancel notification icon.

CODE

```
const NotificationButtons = () => {
      if (condition)  {
        return <Fontisto name='date' size={20} color='#000' onPress={showDatePicker} />
      } else {
        return <Feather name='bell-off' size={20} color='#000' onPress={cancelNotifications} />
      }
    }
```

THE REST OF THE CODES

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

const dateTimePicker = () => {
    const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

    const showDatePicker = () => {
      setDatePickerVisibility(true);
    };

    const hideDatePicker = () => {
      setDatePickerVisibility(false);
    };

    const handleConfirm = date => {
      console.warn("A date has been picked: ", date);
      hideDatePicker();
    };

    const notification = () => {
        PushNotification.configure({
            // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
            onRegister: function(token) {
              console.log("TOKEN:", token);
            },

            // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
            onNotification: function(notification) {
              console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
            },

            // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
            // default: true
            popInitialNotification: true,

            /**
             * (optional) default: true
             * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
             * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
             */
            requestPermissions: true
          });
    }

    const NotificationButtons = () => {
      if (condition)  {
        return <Fontisto name='date' size={20} color='#000' onPress={showDatePicker} />
      } else {
        return <Feather name='bell-off' size={20} color='#000' onPress={cancelNotifications} />
      }
    }

    const sheduledNotifications = (date) => {
        PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
            //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
            priority: 'high',
            message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
            date
          });

    }

    const cancelNotifications = () => {
      PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications();
    }

    return (
      <View>
        <NotificationButtons />
        <DateTimePickerModal
          isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
          mode="datetime"
          onConfirm={sheduledNotifications}
          onCancel={hideDatePicker}
          date={new Date()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  };

  export default dateTimePicker;
```

Comment: I think the problem that is you should refresh the application View. Inside your method, you call the `setState({..})`?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo no i havn't. Would you mind sharing on how you would do it?

Comment: can insert also the code of the method `setDatePickerVisibility`?

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo setDatePickerVisibility doesn't work but setting isDatePickerVisible does change the icon but it sets the icon on all the icons and it doesnt change back when i cancel the notification, maybe im expecting to much out from this code????

Comment: Should be load all code and not the partial code. I don't know wath is the `setDatePickerVisibility` or the `isDatePickerVisible`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I don't really understand what u mean with the latest comment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211502/discussion-between-vincenzopalazzo-and-ilightfps).